# What is a good book about number systems? (decimal, binary.. etc)

Tags: book-recommendation, number-systems

Is there any good math book that talks about number systems? I said "math" book because, most books talk about number systems from the computer science point of view, I would like one that only talks about them, preferably short and not advanced (I need the basics), I was thinking about "Number system and digital logic by Munishwar Gulati" but I'm not sure. You guys got any suggestion?

Comment: Georges IFRAH's "The Universal History of Numbers" http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Ifrah_numbers.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Number theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Number-Theory-Dover-Books-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00B78IWW2/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=number%20theory%20dover&qid=1587468024&sr=8-1)

What about this?